# Are all finitely generated subgroups of SL2 LERF?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory

> Let $H \leq \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a finitely generated
>   subgroup. Must $H$ be LERF?

A group $H$ is said to be LERF (locally extended residually finite), or subgroup separable, if its finitely generated subgroups are closed in the profinite topology on $H$, or equivalently, if each finitely generated subgroup of $H$ is the intersection of some collection of finite index subgroups of $H$.

Comment: No, the Baumslag-Solitar group $\mathrm{BS}(1,4)$ is not LERF. It can be viewed as generated by the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is no longer relevant as it is answered in the comments.

Comment: @YCor Why is the matrix group you describe isomorphic to $BS(1,4)$? I understand that it is a homomorphic image, but why is it isomorphic? I think that $BS(1,4)$ is not resdiually finite while this matrix group is.

Comment: Exercise: every proper quotient of $BS(1,4)$ is virtually cyclic. (And $BS(1,4)$ is residually finite, this is also an exercise)

Comment: @YCor, right, but I am confused. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group I see that this group is not even residually finite, which contradicts the fact that it has faithful linear representation on view of Malcev's theorem.

Comment: Read more carefully. The wiki page does not say that $BS(1,4)$ is not residually finite.

Comment: @YCor many thanks for clarifying! For some reason, I thought that $BS(m,n)$ is not residually finite if at least one of $m,n$ is not $1$. Now I see that they have to be both not $1$ (and different) for the group not to be residually finite.